# bash execute a shell function after a change directory (cd)

Tags: bash, scripting, shell

Trying to find a way to execute a function within BASH after changing into a directory.

for example,

```
# cd code/project/blah
"Your latest modified files are main.cc blah.hpp blah.cc"
(~/code/project/blah) # _
```

With the above I'm hoping to be able to wrap other functionality around the bash command.

Was hoping to find something along the lines of zsh hook functions
http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#SEC45

Comment: That has the potential to be hugely annoying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget about `pushd` and `popd`, unless you never use them. I'd do this:

```
PS1='(\w) \$ '
chdir() {
    local action="$1"; shift
    case "$action" in
        # popd needs special care not to pass empty string instead of no args
        popd) [[ $# -eq 0 ]] && builtin popd || builtin popd "$*" ;;
        cd|pushd) builtin $action "$*" ;;
        *) return ;;
    esac
    # now do stuff in the new pwd
    echo Your last 3 modified files:
    ls -t | head -n 3
}
alias cd='chdir cd'
alias pushd='chdir pushd'
alias popd='chdir popd'
```

Comment: Almost works. `pushd` with no arguments swaps with the top of the dir stack.  `cd` with no arguments changes to the $HOME directory.  Do this instead: `pushd|popd|cd) [[ $# -eq 0 ]] && builtin $action || builtin $action "$*" ;;`.

Comment: Addeded Charles Merriam's suggestion

Answer (score 4):

Use `PROMPT_COMMAND`. You should have a look at git-sh, which includes a lot of fancy git-related tricks and should also be easy to learn from.

Comment: This is also very helpful, but I couldnt mark 2 things as answers :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could make an alias for `cd` which executes the standard `cd` and then some function that you've defined.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet/example on how to do that? How can I make an alias that executes cd which accepts all it's flags and parameters?