# unix - chmod default future permissions for files

Tags: linux, shell, unix, permissions, chmod

I understand that by default when files are created with permissions of chmod 644. Is there anyway to change that so that any files created in a certain folder are by default 664?

Comment: It's not quite correct that files are created with `644` permissions by default.  The default permissions are determined by the creating process's [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) setting.  A umask of `022`, which causes files to be created with `644` permissions, is probably the most common.

Answer (score 4):

The utility to control file creation mode on POSIX systems is called [`umask`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask). I don't think you can apply file creation masks per folder just like that. But, you can use `umask` inside a script. Masks defined in a sub-shell will not affect your regular `umask` (0002) settings.

If you want to automatically change your mask settings when `cd`ing inside a special directory, you can add the following to you bash script (I took the hint on `chdir()` function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443673/bash-execute-a-shell-function-after-a-change-directory-cd) SO post):

```
chdir() {
    local action="$1"; shift
    case "$action" in
        # popd needs special care not to pass empty string instead of no args
        popd) [[ $# -eq 0 ]] && builtin popd || builtin popd "$*" ;;
        cd|pushd) builtin $action "$*" ;;
        *) return ;;
    esac
    #
    # now do stuff in the new pwd
    #
    SPECIAL_DIRS="/tmp/blah1 /tmp/blah2"
    DEFAULT_MASK="0002"
    for dir in $SPECIAL_DIRS
    do
      if [[ "$PWD" == "$dir" ]]
      then
          umask 0007
          echo "[*] special mask settings applied - $(umask -S)"
      else
          umask $DEFAULT_MASK
      fi
    done
    #
    #
}
alias cd='chdir cd'
alias pushd='chdir pushd'
alias popd='chdir popd
```

As you can see, I defined `/tmp/blah1` and `/tmp/blah2` as special directories. Now if I would `cd /tmp/blah1` from regular bash, my `umask` settings will be changed accordingly.

```
[22:45:43] user@host1:[~]$ cd /tmp/blah1
[*] special mask settings applied - u=rwx,g=rwx,o=
[22:45:49] user@host1:[/tmp/blah1]$ cd /tmp/blah2
[*] special mask settings applied - u=rwx,g=rwx,o=
[22:46:03] user@host1:[/tmp/blah2]$
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can make the default group of newly created files and directories to be set to a group of the parent folder - which **probably** work-around your problem:
`chmod g+s <parent-directory>`. Everything that will be created in the `<parent-directory>` will have group ownership of the `<parent-directory>` by default.